# convert txt or doc to pdf using php

Tags: php, pdf

have anyone come across a php code that convert text or doc into pdf ?

it has to  follow the same format as the original txt or doc file meaning the line feed as well as new paragraph...

Comment: or has anyone come across using FPDF that convert txt to pdf ?
I am stuck at reading file from txt file and put them into the same paragraph or carriage line as it is and convert into pdf using FPDF

Comment: let say I have a list of txt files and they could be inside a subdirectories example folder1/abc.txt ,folder1/pqr.txt , folder1/folder2/def.txt etc....

I am looking to write a code that automatically read those txt files and convert it into pdf..but they got to have the same paragraphing as the oiriginal txt file..

Answer (score 4):

Converting from DOC to PDF is possible using [phpLiveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/02/06/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-php/):

```
$phpLiveDocx = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();
$phpLiveDocx->setUsername('username')
            ->setPassword('password');
$phpLiveDocx->setLocalTemplate('document.doc');
// necessary as of LiveDocx 1.2
$phpLiveDocx->assign('dummyFieldName', 'dummyFieldValue');
$phpLiveDocx->createDocument();
$document = $phpLiveDocx->retrieveDocument('pdf');
file_put_contents('document.pdf', $document);
unset($phpLiveDocx);
```

For text to PDF, you can use the [pdf extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php) is PHP.
You can view the examples [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdf.examples-basic.php).

Comment: H iSagi, thanks for your example, unfortunately I don't use Zend framework on the server

Comment: In my experience this is the best tool without using COM in windows server. You don't have to use Zend framework. You do have, however, to download it as some components are required for LiveDocx.

Comment: Using this service, is it possible to convert a word document into pdf on the fly?

Answer (score 1):

See **[HTML_ToPDF](http://www.rustyparts.com/pdf.php)**. It also works for text.

Comment: "word to pdf does" does no longer exist.

Comment: @Gordon http://www.wynia.org/wordpress/2005/06/word-to-pdf-converter-in-php-word2pdf

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586411/is-there-a-free-way-to-convert-rtf-to-pdf). Using OpenOffice in command line mode for conversions can be done, though you'd have to search a bit for the conversion macro's. I'm not saying it's light-weight though :)

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I touched PHP, but if you can make web service calls from it then try [this product](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html). It provides excellent conversion fidelity. It also supports additional formats including Infopath, Excel, PowerPoint etc as well as [Watermarking support](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/06/using-awesome-new-watermarking-features.html).

Please note that I have worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.