# Coverting DOC to PDF programmatically

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

I'm looking for a library to help me convert DOC files to PDF using PHP.

I'm also open to using an external website if this functionality already exists elsewhere, as long as this website has a programmatic API and is free.

Any suggestions how to approach this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=pdf%2bphp&sort=votes&pagesize=50

Comment: @Mike, This search is for `PDF+PHP`. My question is more like `PDF+DOC+PHP`

Comment: possible duplicate of [convert txt or doc to pdf using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348835/convert-txt-or-doc-to-pdf-using-php). @syhuro I only provided that link, in my previous comment, to show that there are hundreds of similar questions.. one of which is the link I just mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at PHP in a very long time, but if you can make web service calls from it then try [this product](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/converting-office-files-to-pdf-format.html). It provides excellent conversion fidelity. It also supports additional formats including Infopath, Excel, PowerPoint etc and has [Watermarking support](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/06/using-awesome-new-watermarking-features.html) as well.

Please note that I have worked on this product so the usual disclaimers apply.

Comment: I have created a PHP example as that question came up a lot. See http://blog.muhimbi.com/2013/02/converting-files-to-pdf-and-other.html

Answer (score 0):

Late but possibly useful as a general reference particularly in light of the "external website" option you mentioned - [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) provides a web-service api for creating doc + pdf + odt + other formats from any application that can invoke a REST web service (or HTTP post).

Answer (score -1):

You can change the file extension of the word file to pdf,by using below code
$filename = preg_replace('".docx$"', '.pdf', $filename);