# Convert to PDF using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I need a simple solution for an issues I'm having. I have an application that allows to upload a document (mostly will be excel files but can be .docx/.doc)

I also am using jsignature to "esign" the document and save that to an image, and all that is working fine.

What I need is a way to convert the uploaded document to PDF, and then merge that with the newly created signature image. Thoughts?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348835/convert-txt-or-doc-to-pdf-using-php

Comment: Excel to PDF can be handled by PHPExcel - http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ and https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel

Answer (score 1):

Fpdf and Fpdi are good PHP plugins to deal with reading/writing PDFs.
I've only ever done the uploading and signing of PDFs but there is probably some way to utilize one of those tools to work with doc/docx files.

http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/fpdi/
[http://www.fpdf.org](http://www.fpdf.org/)