# Linux: Command Line Utility Convert RTF to PDF?

Tags: pdf, rtf, ghostscript

Any recommendations to convert an RTF to a PDF? I need to do this from my LAMP application, so a command line utility like GhostScript would be ideal.

Comment: [This may be useful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22859546/386579)

Comment: use UnRTF, convert to .ps and then ps2pdf to get the pdf. UnRTF also available on Win32

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install ted

/usr/share/ted/Ted/rtf2pdf.sh source-file dest-file
```

or visit this [link](http://www.nllgg.nl/Ted)

Comment: What is `ted`, is there a website or so? It doesn't seem to be part of Ubuntu. Also, did you just [search and paste](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/convert-rtf-to-pdf-263247/) ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek - knew about ted, so I googled it and copypasted the first example I could find which was the link provided by you.

Comment: #sudo apt-get install ted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package ted

Answer (score 25):

Alternatively, you can use libreoffice for this task:

```
libreoffice --headless --invisible --norestore --convert-to pdf source-file.rtf
```

Comment: Persumably there is a version of java already provided with my libreoffice installation, but it sin't found by default:`javaldx: Could not find a Java Runtime Environment!`
`Warning: failed to read path from javaldx`

Answer (score 3):

In my Ubuntu 10.4 I have `unrtf`, which "converts RTF to HTML, LaTeX, Postscript". From Postscript it should be a trivial application of `ps2pdf` to get PDFs.

Comment: My rtf was not well formed, so this utility failed to convert. As long as there is no Ted in ubuntu sources now, I converted my rtf with libreoffice heedless

Answer (score 1):

`unoconv` does this very conveniently.  (FYI, I'm currently using version 0.5-1 of same).  I have to first run a `unoconv --listener &` command, followed by a `unoconv *.rtf` command, for example...

**UPDATE:** I can verify that, on my Debian Jessie machine, version **0.6** of **unoconv** behaves in the above fashion. However, the `unoconv --listener &` command is now no longer necessary (indeed, same seems to cause difficulties if later attempting to open a LibreOffice file...).

Answer (score 0):

Under Cent OS 6, these steps worked for me to convert RTF to PDF from a php file:

1. yum install Ted
2. yum install ghostscript
3. Download rtf2pdf.sh to some path like: /var/www/html/lib, where Apache has sufficient permissions
4. **shell_exec('sh /lib/rtf2pdf.sh /files/test.rtf /files/test.pdf');**