# Convert the RTF to PDF using JAVA which reads the tables in rtf document

Tags: java, itext, rtf

What ways are there to convert an RTF to PDF that contains a table in the document in Windows or Unix using Java?

The option we have tried here are:

- ITEXT - But the table inside the rtf document is not coming properly once converted to PDF. In short the PDF doesn't contain the Table. Here is the code gist. [ITEXT for rtf to pdf java code gist](https://gist.github.com/ajaycs14/0f8cca82a3e083424db3)
- POI - Does apache POI support RTF document parsing? But I found that it is not supported. [POI  support for RTF](http://apache-poi.1045710.n5.nabble.com/Reading-rtf-files-using-POI-HWPF-td2282390.html)
- TIKA - Using Tika I am able  to read the document, but the table in RTFis not parsed correctly and I don't know how to convert it to PDF. [TIKA java code for reading rtf](https://gist.github.com/ajaycs14/25118c89752530007aa6)

We have looked into other options. Is possible to develop or convert RTF to PDF with Java?

[Other options we looked into are in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586411/is-there-a-free-way-to-convert-rtf-to-pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its possible. Take a look at JasperReports!

```
http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library
```

There is also a good API available from Jaspersoft to code your custom PDF-engine and your custom datasource. Start with iReport (UI-Editor).

Comment: Thats great !  Before checking jasperreports-library please can you tell me that  is it possible to do it in java using eclipse editor  ? any tutorial or github repo or  some thing which can help me to get  started for using jasperreports-library . Thanks a lot !

Comment: Yes, you can easy code against the API with eclipse (or some other IDE). Just google "jasperreports create pdf with java":).